# Remove styles using jQuery or any other method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I really need your expert help here!

I'm making a site which will showcase HTML emails. As such I need to remove all styling from within a particular div so I can copy and paste the HTML from the email. That will then maintain the original design of the email.

I've set up a test page [here](http://www.newsletter-examples.com/test/) and tried using removeAttr from jQuery but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm fine with coding HTML and CSS but javaScript is new to me so any really clear examples would be great.

By the way, I'm not hung up on jQuery. Anything that does the job would be brilliant!

Thanks in advance guys,

Brendan.

Here is the JavaSript and HTML

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').removeAttr('style');
    });
</script>
<p>This is a paragraph tag.</p>
<h1>This is a H1 tag.</h1>
<div>
    <p>This is a p tag inside a styled div.</p>
    <table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
table {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
p, address {
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
font-size:19px;
}
h1{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #666666;
}
h1{
    font-family: "Oswald";
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
h1{
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
div{
    background-color:#9F0;
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML/CSS code along with the post.

Comment: You should only need CSS for this. The correct way to do this is to be explicit with your styling, and not have the containing div be styled in the first place.

Comment: jQuery will only remove `style` tags when they are inline styles. Specifying the `border` in the css won't allow jQuery to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("style, link[rel=stylesheet]").remove();
    $("*").removeAttr("style");
});
```

Comment: How do you mean this isn't easily undoable? Does that mean the HTML following that div will also be unstyled?

Comment: @kendalbren I think that pimvdb means that when this code has ran there is no way to bring back the page to how it looked before without refreshing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('your_div').style='';
document.getElementById('your_div').setAttribute("class","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend isolating your page from the html inside the emails using iframes. If you serve the email template content from a different domain from the parent page, then there will be less scope for malicious content to affect your site.

Something like this:

```
<!-- in http://www.company.com/templates/123 -->

<iframe src="http://www.usercontent.com/templates/123.html"></iframe>
```

Without the cross domain barrier, if someone managed to execute javascript inside the template, then it wouldn't be able to go on and steal your user's cookies. Then as a bonus, since the content will be in different pages, you won't have any problems with the CSS mixing between the different pages.

Comment: This seems a good idea, thanks. If I use the iframe on the same domain, are the risks large?

Comment: This is the article I had in mind while making the suggestion: http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/content-hosting-for-modern-web.html